How to polyfill a class/package required for an apk?
There is an apk that I want to use on my phone.
This app relies on a class that is missing from my system installation.
I know what this class needs to do, it is very simple, I have written a jar implementing it.
How do I install this jar into the system so that the apk can use it?

Modifying the APK file would be much easier than modifying the system. The JAR can be converted to DEX then add the dex file into the apk using a file name like classes1.dex. Instead of 1 use the first free number.

Modifying an apk might be possible, but uploading it to PlayMarked is unlikely.
